# What happens when Robocop's Directives come into conflict?

Tags: robocop, robocop-1987

We all knows Prime Directives of Robocop as below.

1. "Serve the public trust"
2. "Protect the innocent"
3. "Uphold the law"
4. "(Classified)"

[image]

For example, if an (innocent) child took a gun and was shooting people what would Robocop do? Would Robocop kill the child, obeying Directive 1, or would he obey Directive 2 to protect the innocent?

**What happens when Robocop's Directives come into conflict?**

Comment: I'm not sure your definition of "innocent" and that of Robocop match here.

Comment: people kindly try to Understand what i'm trying to Ask Here..i'm asking here what will happened if Prime Directives conflict with each other?

Comment: If a person is threatening lives, that person isn't innocent, is he?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Robocop's Prime Directives come into sharp conflict, he generally goes into a system malfunction.

More specifically, Robocop struggles with killing kids, even when they're clearly up to no good.

If he was to come across a child shooting people, the most likely course of action is that he would attempt to interpose himself between the shooter and his potential victims. If he had no other option than to kill the kid, he'd probably go into a spasm.

Obviously, he can always remove those pesky conflicted Directives through the application of Vitamin [V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage)

Comment: when system malfunction Robocop shutdown him self or his system will shutdown?

Comment: @RANSARA009 - He seems to suffer a software malfunction, manifesting as hardware malfunction.

Comment: We see what happens when the directives come into conflict in the first movie, when RoboCop tries to arrest an officer of OCP. Directive 3 comes into direct conflict with the secret directive 4, which basically disables RoboCop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a better example. The scenario you mention has a simple solution: Robocop's awesome targeting would allow him to shoot the gun out of the child's hand.

That was what happened in the movie where he wanted to arrest someone but they had a *"human shield"*.

Video rated for 18 and older:

In [the book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Robocop-Ed-Naha/dp/0440174791), this scene is even more awesome: Robocop shoots the bad guy by ricocheting the bullet several times, confirming his *"computer enhanced"* targeting ability.

Comment: Except that the one occasion we see Robocop targeted by a child, his targeting system registers an error and he's unable to move, let alone shoot the gun out of his hand